# Google maps infobox - maxWidth

Tags: css, google-maps

I'm facing a weird behavior of google maps infobox. I adjusted maxWidth to 0 in order to allow the infobox size adjust to content, but I always get a 236px infobox.

```
var infobox = new InfoBox({
    maxWidth:0
    ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(5, 10)
    ,isHidden:false
    ,closeBoxURL:""
    ,pane: "floatPane"
    ,enableEventPropagation: false
    ,Zindex: null
});
```

If I adjust infobox width in css file as shown bellow I get the same size in every infobox.

```
.infobox {width: 500px;}
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any ideia how to solve this?

Comment: Solved using (white-space:nowrap;) in css file.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `boxStyle` object in the `InfoBoxOptions`

```
boxStyle: {
      whiteSpace: "nowrap"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem, so I retrieved the optimal width and height dynamically and then set my infoBox dimensions accordingly. 
Here's a jQuery function and application of the function that should solve this issue.  I feel the API is really underwhelming on this.

```
getInfoBoxDimensions: function( content ) {
    var sensor = $("<div>").html(content);
    $(sensor).appendTo("body").css({"position" : "absolute", "left" : "-900px"});
    var width = $(sensor).width();
    var height = $(sensor).height();
    $(sensor).remove();
    return new Array(width, height);
},
```

Now you can grab the height and width of html content with the following:

```
var infoBoxDimensions = getInfoBoxDimensions(info_box_html);
```

and set your infoBox using the following:

```
var ib = new InfoBox({
     content : info_box_html,
     boxStyle : {
          width : infoBoxDimensions[0] + "px",
          height : infoBoxDimensions[1] + "px"
     },
     ....
     ....
});
```

Your info_box_html should have its style set to "inline-block".  By default a block element will take 100% width, we only want the exact width of our content, and inline-block will do that for us.

Hope that helps you out

Comment: appending the div to the window just to get the width then removing is a bad idea

Comment: For full html infoboxes do you have a better way?  Setting whitespace nowrap is not a solve-all for more elaborate content, especially content with images, html, and multi-line content. Google Maps, AFAIK, must be passed a width and a height or it sets it automatically, which is not what we want here.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how "correct" this solution but here it goes:

Just set the width and height of the google infobox wrapper to auto and add important to prevent google JS from resizing it:

```
.gm-style-iw {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    div {
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```