# Is "InfoBox" part of the Google Maps javascript API?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In support of my Google Maps project, I am encountering frequent web references in usually reliable sites (such as stackoverflow) to an "InfoBox" element (cf. [Google maps infobox - maxWidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060221/google-maps-infobox-maxwidth)) used along with Marker and InfoWindow. While I'm already familiar with the latter two, I am unable to find any reference to "InfoBox" in the Google Map API.

Is "InfoBox" a part of the Google Maps v3 API? Has it ever been part of the Google Maps API? If not then I'll simply ignore it. If so, then I will greatly appreciate a pointer to relevant documentation.

Comment: By the way, the current version of `@react-google-maps/api` explicitly surfaces InfoBox as one of its components.

It seems overly harsh to keep my question closed when (a) I have edited it to be focused and (b) current npm packages appear to reference it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InfoBox is a third party library that was in the Google GitHub repository at one point. There is a copy of it in my GitHub account:
https://github.com/geocodezip/v3-utility-library/tree/master/archive/infobox

Related question: [Does Google Maps still support InfoBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045993/does-google-maps-still-support-infobox)

Answer (score 0):

I'm promoting the information from geocodezip to an official answer, this appears to be what I was asking about. Here is the link from that comment:

https://github.com/geocodezip/v3-utility-library/tree/master/archive/infobox